# how to use sql join in mysql

Tags: mysql

table name: tbl_schedule

```
tr_id(P.K.)  mr_id(F.K.)   sch_date   doctor_id   
-----------  -----------   --------   ----------
1              23         01/01/2012    32
2              23         05/01/2012    13
3              22         08/01/2012    14
```

Table name: tbl_user

```
mr_id(P.K.)  mr_fname      mr_lname     
-----------  -----------   --------  
23            Manish        malviya    
24            chandan       gerry    
22            jacky         chen
```

Please reply with query thanks
i want to get number of mr between two dates with `mr_fname, mr_lname group by mr_id`
It should look like. in this counting is from tbl_schedule table and mr_fnmae and mr_lname are fetched from tbl_user with reference of mr_id.

one more thing i dont want 0 count

```
mr_fname      mr_lname   count  
-----------   --------  -------
Manish        malviya    2
jacky         chen       1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    select tu.mr_fname, tu.mr_lname, count(ts.mr_id) as `count` 
from tbl_user tu 
inner join tbl_schedule ts on ts.mr_id = tu.mr_id and 
      ts.sch_date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-08-01' 
group by tu.mr_id
```

The above will get you all the users with a row in the schedule it. So the users with a count of 0 will not show up.

```
select tu.mr_fname, tu.mr_lname, count(ts.mr_id) as `count` 
from tbl_user tu 
left join tbl_schedule ts on ts.mr_id = tu.mr_id and 
      ts.sch_date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-08-01' 
group by tu.mr_id
```

This query will select the first name and last name of the user and count the number of times that user id appears in the schedule table.

It does this by grouping by the user id.

And additionally it uses a left join based on user id and date. It is important to put the date condition here so that all users are selected. This is because the left join will include all users that did not match too. But if you put this on the where clause, all users would not be selected. In other words, you will not get a count of zero for 'gerry chandan' if you put the date condition in the where clause. Instead he would be left off the results.

Comment: Yes ts is an alias for table schedule. It counts the mr_id from table schedule. You can change it to ts.tr_id. I don't think it makes a difference. I'll double check though.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it against one of my databases and it shouldn't matter if you count by ts.tr_id or ts.mr_id. I think this is because you are just counting rows here grouped by ts.mr_id

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT b.mr_id, b.mr_fname, b.mr_lname, 
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_schedule a WHERE (a.my_id = b.my_id)
     AND (Date >= '2012-04-01') AND (Date <= '2012-04-20')) AS COUNT
FROM tbl_user
```

You do not need to INNER JOIN, because it seems like you want to include ALL of the users in the tbl_users table.

Edit: You added later that you do not want a count of 0

```
SELECT b.mr_id, b.mr_fname, b.mr_lname, COUNT(*)
FROM tbl_schedule a 
INNER JOIN tbl_users b ON a.tr_id = b.mr_id
WHERE (Date >= '2012-04-01') AND (Date <= '2012-04-20')
GROUP BY b.mr_id, b.mr_fname, b.mr_lname
```

Comment: This request will be much slower than using a join, if you have many records.

Comment: thankx for reply but i dont want all the records from tbl_user i want only the records which is exist in tbl_schedule. all the records between two dates, count the no. of  allocation to each mr. in tbl_schedule table. means how many times mr comes between two date. i want mr_fname and  mr_lname from tbl_user.

Comment: When you join the 2 tables together, you would have to GROUP BY to be able to count, the problem is that you cant do this for a date range.  Use my suggestion and add a where clause to show the records that are not 0

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you need:

```
SELECT
  mr_fname,
  mr_lname,
  COUNT(DISTINCT tr_id)
FROM
  tbl_user
LEFT JOIN
  tbl_schedule USING (mr_id)
GROUP BY
  mr_id
```

Answer (score 0):

> First of all u make sure that you have defined `sch_date` as DATE type
>   AND Database engine should be InnoDb

then it is easy to fetch data as per your question

### QUERY

```
SELECT T2.mr_id,T2.mr_fname,T2.mr_lname,COUNT(doctor_id) FROM tbl_schedule AS T1 INNER JOIN tbl_user AS T2 ON T1.mr_id = T2.mr_id WHERE T1.sch_date > 'date1' AND T1.sch_date < 'date2' GROUP BY doctor_id HAVING COUNT(doctor_id) > 0
```